# website structure - javascript/jquery platform with hash navigation

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I'm trying to find a good and decent structure for a website with a pure javascript/jquery front-end and hash navigation like the famous facebook...

Is the best way to link from page to page with the commonly used `<a href="#the_page"></a>` or are there a more suitable solution for this "new" generation of websites?

I think I also need some kind of on-hash-change so user typed addresses will take affect on the website..

I haven't done this kind of website stuctures before so any good advices and practices are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery BBQ Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is a lifesaver for this type of thing, there's a bunch of examples on how to use it as you scroll down the page.

Hope that helps!