# ASP.Net + MasterPage & dynamic content

Tags: asp.net, css

I was working on a project and was required to have the navigation bar remained static(e.g. facebook), not CSS fixed position but say when I **click an item in the menu** to load its content, **only the content area gets refreshed**.

Hence I believe I will need a container in the center of the page to load the dynamic contents. Right now, the navigation bar is included in all my aspx pages which are identical and the bar refreshes from page to page.

I read several articles/post and the approach I thought of was to wrap every single aspx into usercontrols and then dynamically load it into a div inside my masterpage upon being called from the respective menu items which is based on this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

One of my pages uses jquery tabs to show/hide multiple child div content in a parent div which means all div contents are in one single page, however now I am dealing with 30 over aspx pages which mean this way should be out but that's the concept I need.

Problem is I have over 30 huge aspx pages and not sure if this is the way to go. Any advises for my situation? Thanks.

Comment: you mean you want to make a page dynamicly ? why UserControl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how clean *or dirty* do you want it to be?

Really clean? -> Build a [Single Page Application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application). This will problably make you rewrite a large part of your application.

Old school? -> Use an iFrame and remove (part of?) the MasterPage from your pages.

More dirty? -> Load your content in an [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/). You have to remove the MasterPage from your pages again.

All solutions will present you a navigation challenge, as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287484/website-structure-javascript-jquery-platform-with-hash-navigation).

Answer (score 3):

So you just want your menu bar to remain fixed? Well then make use of the css position property `fixed`.

Wrap your menu bar within a containing `div` and then style that up.

```
div#menu{
    position: fixed;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then give your page content a 25px top margin

```
div#content{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

This will result in your navigation to always remain fixed at the top of the page when you scroll, and you don't need to do anything with pages/usercontrols/dynamically loadingin content.

I have put together a little example here. [CSSDeck Example](http://cssdesk.com/8hKHz)

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry maybe I wasn't clear with my explaination before, it's not CSS fixed position but a navigation bar that doesn't get refreshed. Only the content area will be refresh when I click on any item in the menu bar. A good example will be Facebook, when you click on the menu items on the side, only the right panel gets refreshed.

Comment: Ah ok, well you are not really going to get a smooth solution using UserControls and built in asp.net controls. You would want to take a look at doing this via Ajax. Take a look at jQuery Ajax, Knockoutjs and SammyJs for loading in content, dynamically binding this content to templates and then updating the URL.